# Analogy of Set and Subset and Contracts in abstracto and Marriage in concreto/in particular

Tags: logic, terminology, argumentation, philosophy-of-law, set-theory

I had a talk with a professor of family law and we are frequently told that there are general ordinances for contracts in general and particular ordinances for marriage.

I am problematised by the logic. The general ordinances are only in vigour under the condition that there is no contrasting lex specialis, a contrasting particular ordinance.

So I thought that would lift the generality of the general provisions. They are particular in that they do not hold for all contracts but only for any contracts that are not marriage.

But I was told that the analogy to Euclidean geometry (everything that holds for rhombi necessarily also holds for squares) is inapplicable. Nonetheless, logic and set theory still hold in law as stated by the Professor.

My question: **Does logic and set theory allow for properties holding for all members of a set (something which I identify with generality) not to hold for a particular subset?**

Comment: There are all kinds of properties that you can define on an element relative to the set it is a member of. Like set X = {1,2} Y ={1} Z={2}, define property `alone` for any element that if it is removed the result would be an empty set. Notice how it's true for bot Y and Z but not for X.

Comment: No, they do not allow such properties and neither does law. In legal reasoning "general" is simply used differently. It does not mean general in the usual sense, it means "holds unless specifically overruled".

Comment: @Conifold I do not understand what you mean when you say that Law does not allow for such Properties. It seems to contrast your last sentence. If suddenly general shifted its meaning accordingly wouldn't these properties be suddenly allowed?

Comment: @Ashnur The problem is that 2 does not have the property alone in set X and it has said property in set Z. So the alone property I think would not be one to hold for all members of a set and not hold for a particular subset. If anything that would be a specific property( it only holds for particular subsets and not the superset). I could define a property nalone when 1 and 2 would have the properties in the superset but not the subset but I do not think that would give a positive answer to my question. As it would be a property of the member relative to the set and not of the member in itself.

Comment: In ordinary language we choose to use "straight" loosely, e.g. rulers are "straight". It doesn't mean that anything happens to the properties themselves, only to how we talk about them. "General" legal properties aren't general, strictly speaking, just as rulers aren't straight.

Comment: @GeorgeNtoulos But that's exactly my point. If you want a property that's true in X, invert it: 'not alone'. Both 1 and 2 have the property 'not alone' in X but neither have it in the other sets. 
Basically, what you are after is called the contrapositive in logic https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition
The only way  the subsets' elements don't share all the properties of the parent set if you allow additional questions asked. A general rule is not the most important rule, but a rule to apply if no special concern need to be taken in account for.

Comment: @Conifold Doesn't Law then allow for general properties not to hold for a subset by just shifting "general's" meaning then? If general suddenly became "holds for all members unless specifically overruled" then we do not have any problems in general properties not to hold for a subset as long as there is a specific ordinance to overrule the general ordinance.

Comment: @Ashnur My discussion with Conifold seems more fruiful. I meant to ask for properties of the elements in themselves and not relative to their set. I am only interested in properties of an element which at least hold for that element regardless of the set we are considering( properties that the element has in all sets). Should I edit my question?

Comment: @GeorgeNtoulos if you do not allow exceptions, there are no exceptions. That's logic. As Conifold said it, real life is messier than that. I was trying to say the same thing but differently. You misunderstand that properties that are considering externalities are not 'in' the elements, but it's not important. The point is that you seem to be expecting a level of uniformity from general practice that is impossible to adhere to and which no one is actually trying to achieve, hence the confusion.

Comment: "If general suddenly became "holds for all members unless specifically overruled" then we do not have any problems in general properties not to hold for a subset". Sure, if "general" is meant in the legal sense (it isn't "sudden", general-strictly-speaking is simply not useful in legal practice). But then "general" does not mean "shared by all elements of the parent set" anymore. Just as if we agree to call crooked "straight" there is no problem with calling the hunchback of Notre Dame "straight". But it doesn't change anything about his properties.

Comment: @Conifold Can you write an answer because what you did in the discussion was exactly that? Answer my question? Logic and Set theory do not but the meaning of General in Law has shifted as such General Provisions and not analogous to General Properties.